# What's the correct name for the pop-up text at the bottom of the Windows Edge browser?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-edge

I want to raise a suggestion with Microsoft that the pop-up text that appears in Edge at the bottom as you hover over a URL needs to move out of the way as it interferes with clicking on buttons but I'd like to know what it's called so I can do some searches first to see if it's already been suggested:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the above as it gave me enough information to do a bit more intelligent searching which led me to this entire page on the subject. There doesn't appear to be an official name for it but "URL display popup" seems to be the de facto term.

http://learning-python.com/edge-links-bug.html

Comment: Hmmm, I'd not understand what people mean when reading "URL display popup". I really feel that browser developers (and web developers) will know this as the statusbar.

Comment: ...which, like LPChip wrote, happens to be shown as a tooltip when hovering; a popup sounds like something I need to close myself.

Answer (score 1):

It can either be called the tooltip or statusbar.

I guess I'd call it `The tooltip statusbar that displays the URL of the link pointed at`.

Comment: I'd not call it a tooltip. It's the statusbar indeed, like also defined with that name in HTML5; https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#dom-window-statusbar Also, it's not the "current" URL... ;-)

Comment: It shows up as a tooltip. I edited the definition of current url, because you're right it could mean the page visited, rather than the currently pointed link.

Comment: Let me rephrase that: I'd never call it *just* a tooltip, even though it indeed shows as one when hovering a link. As an aside: does the Edge statusbar really only show on hovering a link? Maybe it also shows for other activity, like "Connecting to ...", in which case it's not really a tooltip?

Comment: The definition of a tooltip is a new window without close button that pops up to show information and automatically goes away again. This definitely is a tooltip.

Comment: I would say a tooltip tends to pop-up close to the element being highlighted so calling it that alone is not correct. In this case, it's revealing the URL under a link so you can check it before clicking - a security feature I assume?

Comment: Pop-up status bar as mentioned here? http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_internet-insider_spartan/microsoft-edge-browser-pop-up-status-bar/7b0fc856-68c7-43a5-a923-4bf01ed2a342?auth=1